# Como yo enviaría el id de una persona a la web para que me traiga solo los datos de ese id? Yo traigo el id por cual me loguie por medio del bundle

Tags: android-asynctask, android-listview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView list;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<Customer> list_cust = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    JSONArray listCust = null;
    String url_read_cust = "http://192.168.0.11/sistema_laravel/public/show_expedientes";
    String id_u;

    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String TAG_CUST = "expedientes";
    public static final String TAG_COD_CUST = "cod_ex";
    public static final String TAG_LUGAR_PROCEDENCIA_CUST = "lugar_procedencia";
    public static final String TAG_CONDICION_CUST = "condicion";
    public static final String TAG_NO_AMBULANCIA_CUST = "no_ambulancia";
    public static final String TAG_CEDULA_CUST = "cedula";
    public static final String TAG_NOMBRE_CUST = "nombre";
    public static final String TAG_SEXO_CUST = "sexo";
    public static final String TAG_EDAD_CUST = "edad";
    public static final String TAG_PULSO_CUST = "pulso";
    public static final String TAG_FRECUENCIA_CUST = "frecuencia_card";
    public static final String TAG_TEMPERATURA_CUST = "temperatura";
    public static final String TAG_GLASGOW_CUST = "glasgow";
    public static final String TAG_SIGNOS_CUST = "signos_vital_ocular";
    public static final String TAG_APLICACION_CUST = "aplicacion_ABC";
    public static final String TAG_CENTRO_CUST = "centro_hospitalario";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCust);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        id_u=bundle.getString("id");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Este es!"+id_u, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        ReadCustTask m = (ReadCustTask) new ReadCustTask().execute();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int urutan, long id) {
                String codcust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cod_cust)).getText().toString();
                String nombrecust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_cust)).getText().toString();
                String lugarcust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lugar_cust)).getText().toString();
                String condicioncust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.condicion_cust)).getText().toString();
                String noambulanciacust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no_ambulancia_cust)).getText().toString();
                String cedulacust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cedula_cust)).getText().toString();
                String sexocust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sexo_cust)).getText().toString();
                String edadcust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edad_cust)).getText().toString();
                String pulsocust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pulso_cust)).getText().toString();
                String frecust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fre_cust)).getText().toString();
                String tempcust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.temperatura_cust)).getText().toString();
                String glascust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.glas_cust)).getText().toString();
                String signoscust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.signos_cust)).getText().toString();
                String aplicust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.aplic_cust)).getText().toString();
                String centrocust = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.centro_cust)).getText().toString();

                Intent i=null;
                i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
                Bundle b= new Bundle();
                b.putString("cod_cust",codcust);
                b.putString("lugar_cust",lugarcust);
                b.putString("condicion_cust",condicioncust);
                b.putString("no_ambulancia_cust",noambulanciacust);
                b.putString("cedula_cust",cedulacust);
                b.putString("nombre_cust",nombrecust);
                b.putString("sexo_cust",sexocust);
                b.putString("edad_cust",edadcust);
                b.putString("pulso_cust",pulsocust);
                b.putString("fre_cust",frecust);
                b.putString("temperatura_cust",tempcust);
                b.putString("glas_cust",glascust);
                b.putString("signos_cust",signoscust);
                b.putString("aplic_cust",aplicust);
                b.putString("centro_cust",centrocust);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }


    class ReadCustTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please waiting...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sText)
        {
            String returnResult = getCustList();
            return returnResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Unable to connect to server, please check your internet connection!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("no results"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
//                list.setAdapter(new CustomerAdapter(ScrollingActivity.this,list_cust));

                list.setAdapter(new CustomerAdapter(MainActivity.this,list_cust));
            }

        }

        public String getCustList()
        {
            Customer tempCust = new Customer();
            List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //    parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_paramedico",id_u));
            try {
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_read_cust,"GET",parameter);

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success==1)
                {

                    listCust = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CUST);
                    for (int i = 0; i < listCust.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject c = listCust.getJSONObject(i);
                        tempCust = new Customer();
                        tempCust.setCod_ex(c.getString(TAG_COD_CUST));
                        tempCust.setLugar_procedencia(c.getString(TAG_LUGAR_PROCEDENCIA_CUST));
                        tempCust.setCondicion(c.getString(TAG_CONDICION_CUST));
                        tempCust.setNo_ambulancia(c.getString(TAG_NO_AMBULANCIA_CUST));
                        tempCust.setCedula(c.getString(TAG_CEDULA_CUST));
                        tempCust.setNombre(c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE_CUST));
                        tempCust.setSexo(c.getString(TAG_SEXO_CUST));
                        tempCust.setEdad(c.getString(TAG_EDAD_CUST));
                        tempCust.setPulso(c.getString(TAG_PULSO_CUST));
                        tempCust.setFrecuencia_cardiaca(c.getString(TAG_FRECUENCIA_CUST));
                        tempCust.setTemperatura(c.getString(TAG_TEMPERATURA_CUST));
                        tempCust.setGlasgow(c.getString(TAG_GLASGOW_CUST));
                        tempCust.setSignos_vital_ocular(c.getString(TAG_SIGNOS_CUST));
                        tempCust.setAplicacion_ABC(c.getString(TAG_APLICACION_CUST));
                        tempCust.setCentro_hospitalario(c.getString(TAG_CENTRO_CUST));
                        list_cust.add(tempCust);

                    }
                    return "OK";

                }

                else{
                    return "no results";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Exception Caught";
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Deberias editar el titulo de la pregunta y ser mas especifico en el con el problema que tienes, y despues ya explicar tu codigo y el error que recibes en el texto de la pregunta, y no en el titulo.

Comment: Es que soy nuevo en esto, primera ves que uso esto ..